# WSDL and type validations

Tags: web-services, wsdl, validation

Since WSDL specifies a section for type definitions, I wonder how this type definitions are enforced so that the message exchange will fail when the contents of the messages don't match the requested types.

According to what I have read, Web Services can exist without a WSDL (just do a quick search for "web services without wsdl"). It's not an ideal situation, but it can happen, and the Web Service can still be used as long as the consumer knows how the message is structured. If this is true, then the types defined in the WSDL are merely informative, aren't they? It seems there isn't an automatic mechanism that binds the type definitions of the WSDL with actual type validations. It seems the [WSDL documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) doesn't say anything in this regard either.

How is type validation usually enforced in Web Services? Is it the server's responsibility to provide such validation and return a failure message if something goes wrong? What is the client's reponsibility when it comes to type validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSDL describes service and part of service description is definition of data exchanged between client and service. Data are described by XML schema (XSD) which defines exact format of each message (except some rare use cases where for example `xsd:any` definition is used). XML schemas are standard way to describe XML documents and they are used to validate these documents - common XML parsers allow you validating the XML document with specified schema.

You can create web service without WSDL - actually WSDL is used mostly for SOAP services but even SOAP services can be defined without WSDL but they can still consume only well defined data which can be described by XSD schemas. Other types of web services like XML service or REST service (passing XML) can also have exchanged data described by XSD.

It depends on consumer if the validation is used. Validation of XML documents can be time consuming and it can reduce throughput of the system. The way how the validation is used depends on the API - some API or tools provide this out of the box other requires manual intercepting of received message and running validation with some available XML parser.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One point remains unclear for me, though. You say "It depends on consumer if the validation is used". Does this mean the provider of the service doesn't do any validation? (I don´t think so, but...) What does it mean exactly?

Comment: @Jong: Sorry, I wasn't clear - consumer is not a client it is message receiver. When client sends request the receiver is service and it is up to service developer if it validates message - XML validation is quite often omitted in internal company application where you get control over both client and service. Once service sends back the response, the client is receiver and it is up to client's developer if XML validation is used. Sometimes XML validation is skipped and deserialized data are validated instead.